# Failure to Lump Constants in Laplace's Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, constants

Consider a $2D$ version of Laplace's Equation, for example, $\triangle u = 0, u(x, 0) = 3, u(x, 1) = 3, u(0, y) = 0, u_x (1, y) = 0$.

Separation of Variables leads to the general solution $u = (Ae^{-\sqrt\lambda x} + Be^{\sqrt\lambda x})(Ce^{-\sqrt{-\lambda} y} + De^{\sqrt{-\lambda} y})$, which has five constants to be determined, $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $\lambda$.  We can use the two homogeneous boundary conditions to solve for $A$ in terms of $B$, and also solve for $\lambda$, yielding $u = (Be^{\frac{(2n + 1)\pi x i}{2}} - Be^{-\frac{(2n + 1)\pi x i}{2}})(Ce^{-\frac{(2n + 1)\pi y}{2}} + De^{\frac{(2n + 1)\pi y}{2}})$.

The next step is to lump $B$ into $C$ and $D$.  Then the two inhomogeneous boundary conditions can be used to solve for the new $C$ and $D$, in general via Fourier Series, but in this case via ordinary algebra.  Optionally, Euler's formula can be applied around this point to get trig answers instead of complex exponentials.

However, if we fail to lump $B$ into $C$ and $D$ before applying the inhomogeneous boundary conditions, then it is possible to solve for $C$ and $D$, but leave $B$ in the final solution.

If this "mistake" has been made, is there a way to reason though what $B$ should be using the boundary conditions or other information about the problem, without retracing previous steps in the solution technique to lump away $B$, or has the information to pin down this degree of freedom genuinely been lost as a result of doing the algebra in a suboptimal manner, even though all of the information given has been applied?  If the latter, is this phenomenon special in the algebra of differential equations, or is there a high-school algebra or linear algebra equivalent that would provide a more intuitive understanding of the nature this type of information loss?

Comment: I don't understand what the $A,B,C,D,\lambda$ represent.

Comment: Certainly the linear algebra and algebra-precalculus tags are a stretch. I think you're going to have to sketch an example of the procedure you're describing so abstractly. It's impossible for me to sort this out as you've stated it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could figure out what was going on if I knew what $A,B,C,D,\lambda$ were supposed to mean.

Comment: @Ian I added an example to clarify.

Comment: @TedShifrin ^^^

Comment: I still don't really understand what the problem is. Yes, once $A$ is known it is possible to consolidate to have the only parameters in the problem be $BC$ and $BD$, but because of that, $B$ wasn't uniquely determined in the first place. And indeed it isn't; if you replace $A,B$ by $cA,cB$ and $C,D$ by $c^{-1} C,c^{-1} D$ where $c$ is any nonzero constant, then you have the same function written in a different form.

Comment: You have been sloppy in throwing around parameters, as they are not independent. Think about solving for the equation of a plane $Ax+By+Cz=0$. There are two parameters here (think of the normal vector on a unit sphere), not three.